# allowmarkup bug causing texttab to be shared

Tags: docusignapi

Everything works fine until the first signer clicks 'Mark Up' under 'Other Actions' during the signing process. When that happens the TextTab (that is not set to be shared) for the second signer becomes available for the first signer to type into. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to configure the API to avoid this situation.

Here is the Json sent (captured with Fiddler and sensitive data was changed), sorry for the size.

```
{
    "allowMarkup":"True",
    "documents":
    [
        {
            "documentBase64":"abc123...",
            "documentId":"1",
            "name":"Contract"
        }
    ],
    "emailBlurb":"This is a test email blurb",
    "emailSubject":"This is my email subject.",
    "enableWetSign":"False",
    "eventNotification":
    {
        "envelopeEvents":
        [
            {"envelopeEventStatusCode":"sent"},
            {"envelopeEventStatusCode":"completed"},
            {"envelopeEventStatusCode":"declined"},
            {"envelopeEventStatusCode":"voided"}
        ],
        "includeCertificateOfCompletion":"True",
        "includeCertificateWithSoap":"False",
        "includeDocumentFields":"True",
        "includeDocuments":"True",
        "includeEnvelopeVoidReason":"True",
        "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField":"True",
        "includeTimeZone":"True",
        "signMessageWithX509Cert":"False",
        "url":"http://MyWebApi.com/DocumentCompleted",
        "useSoapInterface":"False"
    },
    "recipients":
    {
        "signers":
        [
            {
                "email":"me@me.com",
                "name":"first signer",
                "recipientId":"1",
                "routingOrder":"1",
                "tabs":
                {
                    "dateSignedTabs":
                    [
                        {
                            "anchorCaseSensitive":"False",
                            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":"False",
                            "anchorMatchWholeWord":"True",
                            "anchorString":"First Signer Signature",
                            "anchorUnits":"Inches",
                            "anchorXOffset":"2.2",
                            "anchorYOffset":"-0.2",
                            "name":"First Signer Signature",
                            "recipientId":"1",
                            "tabId":"First Signer Signature"
                        }
                    ],
                    "signHereTabs":
                    [
                        {
                            "anchorCaseSensitive":"False",
                            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":"False",
                            "anchorMatchWholeWord":"True",
                            "anchorString":"First Signer Signature",
                            "anchorUnits":"Inches",
                            "anchorXOffset":"0.04",
                            "anchorYOffset":"-0.27",
                            "name":"First Signer Signature",
                            "recipientId":"1",
                            "tabId":"First Signer Signature"
                        }
                    ],
                    "textTabs":
                    [
                        {
                            "anchorCaseSensitive":"False",
                            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":"False",
                            "anchorMatchWholeWord":"True",
                            "anchorString":"First Signer Name and Title",
                            "anchorUnits":"Inches",
                            "anchorXOffset":"-0.07",
                            "anchorYOffset":"-0.2",
                            "maxLength":45,
                            "name":"First Signer Name and Title",
                            "recipientId":"1",
                            "required":"True",
                            "shared":"False",
                            "tabId":"First Signer Name and Title",
                            "tabLabel":"First Signer Name and Title"
                        },
                        {
                            "anchorCaseSensitive":"False",
                            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":"False",
                            "anchorMatchWholeWord":"True",
                            "anchorString":"CONTACT Print Name",
                            "anchorUnits":"Inches",
                            "anchorXOffset":"-0.07",
                            "anchorYOffset":"-0.2",
                            "maxLength":45,
                            "name":"CONTACT Print Name",
                            "recipientId":"1",
                            "required":"True",
                            "shared":"False",
                            "tabId":"CONTACT Print Name",
                            "tabLabel":"CONTACT Print Name"
                        },
                        {
                            "anchorCaseSensitive":"False",
                            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":"False",
                            "anchorMatchWholeWord":"True",
                            "anchorString":"CONTACT Email Address",
                            "anchorUnits":"Inches",
                            "anchorXOffset":"0.07",
                            "anchorYOffset":"-0.2",
                            "maxLength":45,
                            "name":"CONTACT Email Address",
                            "recipientId":"1",
                            "required":"True",
                            "shared":"False",
                            "tabId":"CONTACT Email Address",
                            "tabLabel":"CONTACT Email Address"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "email":"me2@me.com",
                "name":"Second Signer",
                "recipientId":"2",
                "routingOrder":"2",
                "tabs":
                {
                    "dateSignedTabs":
                    [
                        {
                            "anchorCaseSensitive":"False",
                            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":"False",
                            "anchorMatchWholeWord":"True",
                            "anchorString":"Second Signer Signature",
                            "anchorUnits":"Inches",
                            "anchorXOffset":"2.2",
                            "anchorYOffset":"-0.2",
                            "name":"Second Signer Signature",
                            "recipientId":"2",
                            "tabId":"Second Signer Signature"
                        }
                    ],
                    "signHereTabs":
                    [
                        {
                            "anchorCaseSensitive":"False",
                            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":"False",
                            "anchorMatchWholeWord":"True",
                            "anchorString":"Second Signer Signature",
                            "anchorUnits":"Inches",
                            "anchorXOffset":"0.04",
                            "anchorYOffset":"-0.27",
                            "name":"Second Signer Signature",
                            "recipientId":"2",
                            "tabId":"Second Signer Signature"
                        }
                    ],
                    "textTabs":
                    [
                        {
                            "anchorCaseSensitive":"False",
                            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":"False",
                            "anchorMatchWholeWord":"True",
                            "anchorString":"Second Signer Name and Title",
                            "anchorUnits":"Inches",
                            "anchorXOffset":"-0.07",
                            "anchorYOffset":"-0.2",
                            "maxLength":45,
                            "name":"Second Signer Name and Title",
                            "recipientId":"2"
                            ,"required":"True",
                            "shared":"False",
                            "tabId":"Second Signer Name and Title",
                            "tabLabel":"Second Signer Name and Title"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status":"sent"
}
```

Comment: Can you please shows us your request (json) to create the envelope.

Answer (score 1):

When "Markup" is chosen, fields behave differently. The [docs](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-document-markup) say:

> Normally, fields are only visible and actionable by the recipient to whom they are assigned. For text, radio button, drop down, and check box fields, you can choose to set the collaboration property, which makes the fields visible and actionable by all recipients on the transaction. If you use document markup, these field types become collaborative automatically when the markup feature is activated by a recipient.

**So the issue is how to set the `collaboration property` property.**

I did some investigation, it looks like the `shared` property in the API is the `collaboration property` in the UX. (The API property names often diverge from the UX names as we get results from UX testing.)

I see that you're setting it to false.

**Things to try**

First try to duplicate the behavior from the web tool: if you send an envelope with a text field that has "collaboration" off, and a different signer chooses "MarkUp" does the signer have the ability to change the non-collaborative field? If so, then it is a bug with the implementation.

In your tests, none of the signers should be the sender of the envelope since the sender, in some cases, has additional privileges.

If not, then the issue is at the API level and we'll investigate there.

I would also try not setting the `shared` property since its default is false.

Comment: Larry, thanks for the quick response. I did not catch that detail in the documentation. So, it looks like it is functioning as designed. I have tried the suggestions that you gave - they all do the same thing. I think I will just have to make the text tab read only - not the ideal implementation for me.